# Are there languages with more vowels than consonants?

Tags: list-of-languages, vowels, consonants, phoneme-inventories

Almost all languages of the world have more consonants than vowels. Are there some languages of the world with more vowel phonemes than consonants?

Comment: Can someone post an answer involving whistling languages? I can't quite do it.

Comment: @Joshua there are no natural whistled languages, only whistled registers of spoken languages (the key fact here is that they encode a language whose default mode is spoken, rather than being languages that are primarily whistled; in the case of the famous silbo gomero, it is a whistled register of Spanish). The consonant/vowel distinction is not really maintained in whistling, so I don't think the question could really be applied to them, any more than it could to sign languages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have yet to see anyone bring up the [Iau language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iau_language#Phonology) of West Papua, Indonesia, which has only 6 phonemic consonants (not counting allophony) but 8 vowel qualities even before accounting for diphthongs and tones.

Comment: Another nice example from the Lakes Plain family.

Answer (score 21):

Probably the best-known and most often-cited example of this is [Danish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_phonology).

Danish is generally said to have around 17 or 18 consonant phonemes, a fairly invariant number. The number of vowel phonemes cited varies a lot more, because there’s some serious interplay going on between morphophonemes, phonemes and phones, but it’s very difficult to reduce the vowel system to less than 20 vowels – generally, around 20 or 21 morphophonemic vowels and around 25–28 vowel phonemes are cited.

Answer (score 12):

The conventional understanding of "phoneme" is that it is a segment. There is vast disagreement over what constitutes a "segment". Given that, one example of a language with many more vowels than consonants is Vietnamese, which has 84 vowels and 19 consonants. To put the matter in more familiar terms, are [ɛ] and [ɛ̃] in French one vowel or two? Akan has a vowel distinction "Advanced Tongue Root" which is contrastive – are [e] and [e̟] two vowels or one? Various languages have two or three degrees of vowel length: are Estonian [a, a:, a::] one vowel or three?

There are various analytic methods for eliminating vowel from the list of phonemes, factoring out orthogonal properties that are available to vowels in general. Without systematic criteria for saying whether a vowel property is to be taken into consideration (and please note that all of my examples *are* phonemic), it is likely that "more vowels than consonants" is actually a very common feature of languages.

Comment: Your Vietnamese example works only if you count all the diphthongs and triphthongs as separate vowels. The orthography recognises only 9 vowels and 6 tones.

Comment: Diphthongs and triphthongs *are* often treated as separate vowels, just as "prenasalized stops" and affricates are often treated as separate phonemes. Likewise there is a debate as to whether Chinese has [k, kʷ] as phonemes, of [k,w] and some clusters.

Comment: For the sake of this question: The clearer the vowel majority is, the better. When there is a vowel majority without invoking tone, length, and diphthongs the example is just perfect.

Comment: @fdb English orthography "recognizes" five or six vowels, but there are far more vowels actually used. The mapping of phonemes to letters is never one to one.

Comment: @PCLuddite. In the case of Vietnamese the assumption of 9 vowel phonemes is an adequate and economical phonological analysis, with tone as a super-sequential feature.

Comment: @fdb: did you mean "suprasegmental"?

Comment: @TonyK. probably.

Answer (score 6):

In general, languages with fewer consonants will have more vowels (and vice versa), so as to have as many unique syllables as possible and preserve redundancy. (Danish is an exception.)

- **Hawaiian** has eight consonant phonemes and twenty-five vowels (including diphthongs & long vowels). If you don't include diphthongs, it still has ten vowels, including the long vowels.
- **Danish** has around seventeen consonant phonemes and around twenty-six vowel phonemes.
- **Apinayé** is analyzed as having seventeen consonants and seventeen vowels.
- **Finnish** has fourteen native consonants (a few more are found in loanwords) and sixteen vowels (including long vowels). Edit: Including diphthongs, it has thirty-four vowels.

Comment: When counting length in vowels, shouldn't length in consonants (gemination)  also be counted as distinguishing feature? This would change the balance for Finnish.

Comment: Rotokas technically fails the OP's requirement, but comes really close, with 5 vowels and 6 consonants.

Comment: @SirCornflakes I suppose so; however, the phonology charts I see don't show geminates. On the other hand, geminates are sometimes analyzed as sequences of two of the same consonant (e.g. *akka* is [ak.ka]), but I guess by that logic, diphthongs shouldn't count, taking Hawaiian off the list.

Comment: @nearsighted But diphthongs are usually vowels that change in quality as they progress. They are often vectors rather than a sequence of two vowels. I'm not sure what the situation is in Hawaiian though.

Comment: @Araucaria-him Well, as I think about it I suppose you're right. But they're still written either as two vowels or as a vowel followed by a glide.

Comment: if you count long vowels as distinct from short vowels (in Finnish), should you also count vowel combinations as distinct? i.e. _sana_ != _Saana_ != _sauna_

Comment: @ilkkachu Do you mean diphthongs?

Comment: @nearsighted, I guess that's what they're called.

Comment: @ilkkachu I counted diphthongs for Hawaiian; forgot to include them for Finnish though ─ thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Other languages likely have more unbalanced ratios than this, but for interest' sake, the Tai-kadai languages (Thai, Lao, Shan, etc.) have a few more vowel phonemes than consonant phonemes.  This is not true, however, of their graphemes, as many consonants have multiple grapheme representations.

Taking the Thai as the dominant example, we can represent its sounds as follows.

**CONSONANTS**

| Approximate Phoneme | Thai Grapheme(s) |
| --- | --- |
| b | บ |
| bp | ป |
| ch | ช / ฉ / ฌ |
| d | ด / ฎ |
| dt | ต / ฏ |
| f | ฟ / ฝ |
| gk | ก |
| h | ห / ฮ |
| j | จ |
| k | ค / ข / ฃ / ฅ / ฆ |
| l | ล / ฬ / ฦ |
| m | ม |
| n | น / ณ |
| ng | ง |
| p | พ / ผ / ภ |
| r | ร / ฤ |
| s | ซ / ส / ษ / ศ |
| t | ท / ฑ / ธ / ฐ / ถ |
| w | ว |
| y | ย / ญ |

NOTES: The "w" and "y", like in English, can also function as vowels, and the "r" also sometimes functions as a vowel in Thai.  Lao lacks the "ch" and officially it lacks the "r" (which it had in the past, but officials have "simplified" the language, converting the "r" to either an "h" or an "l" in pronunciation), so it has even fewer consonants than Thai.

**VOWELS**

| Approximate Phoneme | Thai Grapheme(s) |
| --- | --- |
| ah | -า |
| aht | -ะ |
| i | -ี |
| it | -ิ |
| eu | -ื |
| eut | -ึ |
| u | -ู |
| ut | -ุ |
| ae | แ- |
| aet | แ-ะ |
| e | เ- |
| et | เ-ะ |
| o | โ- |
| ot | โ-ะ |
| au | -อ |
| aut | เ-าะ |
| euu | เ-อ |
| euut | เ-อะ |
| ia | เ-ีย |
| iat | เ-ียะ |
| eua | เ-ือ |
| euat | เ-ือะ |
| ua | -ัว |
| uat | -ัวะ |
| ai | ไ- / ใ- |

NOTES: The dash/hyphen in the grapheme column represents a consonant.  (Some will still show the hollow circle to indicate a missing grapheme.)  No vowel in Thai or Lao can be written without a consonant to which it is attached (Shan is written in Burmese script, with similar rules).  The "t" represents a shortened vowel in which the sound cuts off abruptly almost as if culminating in a "t" in English.

Adding them all up, the vowels (inclusive of diphthongs and long/short vowels--which are, to the speakers of the language, entirely different phonemes), vowels outnumber consonants by a small margin (about 25 to 20).  In Lao, this margin is increased, as Lao lacks some of the consonants which Thai uses, and might be said (debatably) to have one or two vowels which Thai does not have.

Comment: “Officials” didn’t “simplify the language” to convert /r/ to /h/ or /l/; that’s not how sound change works. The change happened naturally and gradually in regular speech, not because any officials decreed that it should happen: /r/ became /h/ initially in monosyllabic words and /l/ elsewhere. It’s not known when exactly the latter change happened (though it had definitely happened by the early 20th century), but the change to /h/ seems to have happened around 500 years ago.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I could be more specific, actually.  It was a recent king of Laos, just prior to Communism taking over in the country, who reduced the alphabet and removed certain consonants from it, including the "r".  I have spoken with native Lao people, within Laos, who explained this--note that Wikipedia does not appear to have the full details, but a brief mention of the fact that the "r" "was dropped as part of a language reform" can be seen [HERE.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lao_script)

Comment: @Biblasia: that sounds more like a spelling reform than a language reform. It didn't change the language, just the way it was written.

Comment: While this answer contains a good insight, it "unfairly" favors vowels over consonants. Namely, it promotes vowel clusters (like `ia` and `ua`) into full-featured vowel sounds while discourages consonant clusters (like `kr`, `khr`, `kl`, `khl`, `kw`) at all. It promotes vowel duration (thus promoting `a` and `a:` into two full-featured ones) but discourages the final values of many consonants (e.g. written/initial `r` becoming final `n`) etc. Thankfully, it did not consider lexical tones; that would multiply the whole multitude of vowels by 5.

Comment: @TonyK I should also note that in addition to simplifying the Lao script, one of the purposes of the king was political in nature.  He deliberately wanted the Lao language to be _different_ from Thai, hence the removal of certain consonants, and pressure placed on the population to adopt the revised pronunciations.

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine From an outsider's perspective, you make a valid point.  From within the language, however, those consonant clusters are treated as combinations of separate phonemes, not new phonemes.  For example, the "ng" and "ch" are distinct and indivisible phonemes, but something like "kr" is divisible into its "k" and "r" components--which is why I do not count "kr" as its own consonant.

Comment: @Biblasia As Tony mentioned, this was a change in **writing**, not in speaking. The /r/ _sound_ (note the /phoneme slashes/, rather than ⟨grapheme brackets⟩) had disappeared much earlier, and reforming the alphabet was just a way to catch up with the existing change in pronunciation. Spelling reforms like that are common, but they don’t affect the inventory of actual sounds used in the language.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I speak, read, and write Lao.  I can assure you that the _spellings_ with the "r" very much exist.  However, it is not pronounced as an "r".  If one says "โรงเรียน/rongrien" (school) in Thai, the "r" is like the rolled "r" of Spanish.  But if one speaks this word in Lao, it (ໂຮງຮຽນ) is pronounced as "honghien."  However, in "borisut" (pure), the "r" becomes an "l", i.e. "bolisut." This is reflected in the spelling (Lao: ບໍລິສຸດ vs. Thai: บริสุทธิ์). Lao actually has _two_ "r" characters (ຮ/ຣ), in addition to characters for "l" (ລ) and for "h" (ຫ). They just aren't pronounced.

Comment: @Biblasia I know they exist, and that they’re not pronounced with a [r] sound. But they were not pronounced with [r] _before_ the alphabet reduction you mention either. Officials didn’t suddenly tell everyone in Laos, “You cannot pronounce the sound [r] anymore – from now on, you have to pronounce it as either [h] or [l]”. **That did not happen.** What happened was that, about 500 years ago, in word-initial position, the original /r/ phoneme (written ຣ) _naturally_ started to be pronounced first as unvoiced [r̥], then later on as [h]; i.e., it merged with the previously distinct phoneme /h/. →

Comment: → The letter ຮ (a variation of ຣ) was probably invented while that change was happening, perhaps to denote the difference between [r] and [r̥]. Some time later (no one knows exactly when, but definitely no later than the late 19th or early 20th century), the remaining instances of /r/, such as in _borisut_, started being pronounced as [l], merging with the previously distinct phoneme /l/. When that happened, Lao no longer had any [r] **sounds** at all, but the words were still **written** with the original letters, so you could see whether a word had _originally_ contained an /r/ or not. →

Comment: → It wasn’t until a long time after that that the **spelling** reform you mentioned above took place, seeking to get rid of this complication by just writing words as they are pronounced. The reform you mention changed the **letters**, but the **sounds** had already changed much earlier.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Where are you getting your information? Did you catch that fact I mentioned earlier that in the case of "borisut" there _was_ a spelling change? You seem not to have followed that one.  I assume Lao is not one of your languages. Until you have an intimate knowledge of Laos, it is likely you will place undue confidence in English-language sources for information on this subject. The only spelling reform on the "r" was the removal of one of them--the other remained. The removed "r" has been reintroduced. Many Lao words have dual spellings (with/without "r" and/or combined "h").

Comment: If you’d read and understood my comments, you would know that I _did_ catch that, yes. But it’s clear you’re not understanding anything that I’m saying, despite my attempts to make it as clear as possible, so I’ll not try any further. I’ll just say that this statement from your answer is incorrect: “officials have "simplified" the language, converting the "r" to either an "h" or an "l" in pronunciation”.

Comment: @Biblasia I can't believe that anyone would believe that government officials would have the ability to consciously change the language's pronunciation. Spelling, yes, but not pronunciation.

Comment: @nearsighted Not just pronunciation, but vocabulary/language itself has been changed by governments.  Consider Franco's regime in Spain, per the scant details offered via [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_policies_of_Francoist_Spain)  There is much more to that story, as the older generation in Spain might still remember.

Comment: @Biblasia All Franco did was ban the usage of languages other than Spanish, including in names. There is no record, among the scant details offered (which, as Wikipedia helpfully notes *right* at the top of the article, have multiple issues), of any change to the vocabulary or grammar. And not everyone would obey, anyway.

Comment: @nearsighted I studied some of this history, in Spanish, while in Spain, but that was decades ago.  I remember clearly that the people chafed at the policies, and when Franco was gone, the local dialects again emerged.  But those policies did affect the language in lasting manner.

Comment: @Biblasia Please give an example of a linguistic policy that Franco enacted other than making Spanish the only official language.

Comment: @nearsighted Franco prohibited the local dialects from being used.  Effectively, this meant that, for example, Valenciano (the dialect of the region of Valencia) could not be used in legal documents or public venues.  The same would be true for each of Spain's other regions, e.g. Madrileño for Madrid, Andaluciano for Andalucia, etc.  In Andalucia, the "ceta" (C) is pronounced as "S" whereas in other parts of Spain it is pronounced as "TH"--how this was affected during Franco's time I do not know, but it's almost like a lisp--the Andalucians seem unable to pronounce the "TH".

Comment: @Biblasia So all he did was try to force some people to pronounce /s/ as /θ/? (By the way, there's no need to have the English approximations for the Thai vowels in your post. We've all studied linguistics here; the IPA would work much better.)

Comment: @nearsighted I have studied IPA at a master's degree level, and I do not like the system.  It poorly represents, or even lacks, many of the phonemes that I deal with on a day-to-day basis in the Asian languages, and seems much better suited to the more traditional European language family.  In any case, I avoid using IPA to avoid these weaknesses.  If only there were a better system....but alas, one cannot even well hear a sound, much less pronounce or represent with a symbol, that he or she did not learn in early childhood.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet (fyi, Janus, this argument is still going) Biblasia: the IPA represents quite nicely all of the complicated tones of the Tai-Kadai, Sino-Tibetan, and other tonal Asian families. But getting back to the point of our discussion, it seems all Franco did was try to force people to pronounce /s/ as /θ/. That's not a significant change, and amounts only to forcing people to speak in a certain dialect ─ not as extreme as your Thai example above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145758/discussion-between-nearsighted-and-biblasia).